# How to set v-treeview mandatory in vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

when we click a treeview node,the treeview node will turn grey but we click it again,the blue or grey background will disappear but the activeitem still be there .
I hope the grey background can hold all the time so that i will keep the same with activeitems.

[image]

[image]

We all know the list-item-group etc has mandatory attribute to controll there are always